# Get request body in Quarkus Interceptor

Tags: quarkus, interceptor, vert.x

I have written an interceptor in Quarkus based application.

```
@AccessPolicy  //custom annotation
@Interceptor
public class PolicyInterceptor {
  
  @AroundInvoke
  Object authorize(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {

  HttpServerRequest request = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance().getContextData(HttpServerRequest.class);
  String tenantId = request.getHeader("tenant-id");
  //business logic here which needs request body
  return context.proceed();
}
```

There are some rest APIs which are annotated with @AccessPolicy and this interceptor is properly intercepting them.
I am able to get header value from the request (request.getHeader("tenant-id")).

Somehow body is not available in the HttpServerRequest object.

PS: I can't use ContainerRequestFilter as I need InvocationContext for the business logic. Please suggest if there is any other way which gives me both request body and invocation context.

Comment: Why exactly do you need `InvocationContext`?

Comment: @geoand I need rest API method name which was called to check authorization. For e.g. getAccount(). Request body is also required for authrization check.

Comment: You can get that information in a `ContainerRequestFilter` by using a `@Context ResourceInfo resourceInfo` field. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ContainerRequestFilter` worked for me as I needed `InvocationContext` only to get the method name of the Rest API and it was available in the ContainerRequestContext.

```
String methodName = ((PostMatchContainerRequestContext) requestContext).getResourceMethod().getMethod().getName();
```